# Does Nginx have an equivalent of IIS Virtual apps?

Tags: linux, nginx

In IIS you can host multiple web applications under one site, e.g. example.com/{application1} and have example.com/{application2} is there any equivalent on Nginx (or any Linux based web server) where you can do something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, there is [`location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) syntax where you can declare the rules on how to process different URIs, for example

```
server example.com;
location /app1 {
    # config for application 1 (served under example.com/app1 prefix)
}
location /app2 {
    # config for application 2 (served under example.com/app2 prefix)
}
```

Locations can be declared using regex matching rules. You can serve files from different directories, proxy requests to different backends etc.